# How to show the following about expectations

Tags: probability-theory, expectation

If $X$ is $\mathcal{M}_1$ measurable on a probability space, $\mathcal{M}_2\subseteq\mathcal{M}_1$ and $Y$ is $\mathcal{M}_2$ measurable and they satisfy $E(XI_A)=E(YI_A)$ for every $A\in\mathcal{M}_2$, how would I be able to show that $E(XZ)=E(YZ)$ for every $Z$, $\mathcal{M}_2$ measurable? I have tried to approximate $Z$ by events of the type $I_{A_n}$ but for some reason cant seem to get it work.

Comment: Where do you get stuck when trying to approximate $Z$ by simple functions?

Comment: @StefanHansen  I get stuck in second guessing whether that is the right thing to do.

Comment: It is, so can you complete your proof now?

Comment: @mathemagician Are you familar with conditional expectations?

Comment: @saz I observe that the condition involving $I_A$ is the definition of a conditional expectation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hints:**

1. The condition $\mathbb{E}(X 1_A) =  \mathbb{E}(Y 1_A)$ for all $A \in \mathcal{M}_2$ implies $Y = \mathbb{E}(X \mid \mathcal{M}_2)$.
2. Use tower property: $$\mathbb{E}(X Z) = \mathbb{E} \big( \mathbb{E}(X Z \mid \mathcal{M}_2) \big) = \dots$$

**Remark:** Note that we need some integrability assumption on $Z$; otherwise $\mathbb{E}(XZ)$ might not even be well-defined.

Comment: Can I pull out a $Z$ outside of the inner expectation? I think I can, since $Z$ is $\mathcal{M}_2$-measurable.

Comment: @mathemagician Yes, exactly.